# Cyclic convolution between two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

How can I perform cyclic (periodic) convolution between two matrices in Matlab? And also, what would be the normalization term?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Is there something missing from the documentation?

Comment: There only seem to be a function called cconv for vectors that doesn't work for matrices.

Comment: a matrix in matlab can be 1D, 2D or nD. I think you have a 2D matrix, that's why you cannot use conv directly ?

Comment: Yes, I got a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `cconv2` does not exist, you can do it with the Fourier transform and multiplication:

```
A = some_MxN_matrix;
B = some_KxP_matrix;
Mfft = max(M,K);
Nfft = max(N,P);
C = ifft2( fft2(A,Mfft,Nfft) .* fft2(B,Mfft,Nfft) );
```

Hopefully the above helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any normalization factor I should take into account?